# Does the series $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{a^{\sqrt{n}}}$ converge for $a<1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Show that the following series converge on $\mathbb{C}$:
>
> $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{z^n}{a^{\sqrt{n}}}$ where $z\in\mathbb{C}$ is a variable and $a>0$.

I f I apply the root test I get $\lim_{n\to\infty}|z|a^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}=|z|$ so it converges if $|z|<1$. However it was pointed out that if $a<1$ the series do not converge.

**Question:**

How can I prove that the series does not converge for $a<1$? For $a<1$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}|z|a^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}=|z|$ still holds?

Comment: You applied the root test correctly. Why do you doubt it?

Comment: @zhw.        Because it was told me that the series would diverge for $a<1$ and I do not understand why.

Comment: Who told you so?

Comment: @ClementC. The Professor.

Comment: The professor is wrong, and it's weird that you think otherwise since the root test is simple here.